# cant load external page using ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I've tried to load external html page on same server using **jQuery**  `.load()` by clicking on div , but it just doesn't work ! I tried using examples of `$.get` or `$.post` from Jquery API website . but every time I found this error in my chrome console :

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`

every correct answers on Stackoverflow also had same results .

I know a little of JavaScript,Jquery and php . can somebody help me out here ?

**Extra Notes** : I've also tested my codes in XAMP local server ;

I've tried many ways , the last time my code was :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#reslink').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "2.html",
                    data: { },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#maincont').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Javascript:void(0);" id="reslink">link1</a>
    <div id="maincont">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**new:**
I tested the same code in online free webhost and it just worked there ! I still cand understand the reason why it didnt work in xamp server !

Comment: can you write your whole code?

Comment: I suggest to use $.ajax method and write html in sucuss event

Comment: You've set `async:false` which is a big no-no, that's what the error message is about

Comment: No idea how you are getting that error using `load()` since you can't set `async` option unless you have set it globally

Comment: I posted my code in my edits , check it out . + this is just one way I tried . thanks @ChintanGor

Comment: @charlietfl : whats `async` option ?

Comment: @adeneo : whats `async` option ? how can I make a change ?

Comment: @sepehr can read about it in the api docs. Are you running this on a server or from local file? can't use ajax from local file without over riding browser settings

Comment: I'm running this on Local Server -> XAMP ;

is that the problem ? @charlietfl

Comment: You need to run it from a server anyway (like Xamp) to be able to make ajax calls, so no, it's not a problem.

Comment: no, should work fine if opening `localhost/path/tofile`. Very strange issue you have. Try another browser

Comment: The code looks correct right now, I don't see why it would fail. What does the console say?

Comment: @sepehr I have not any problem in running your code

Comment: Well, somewhere you're doing synchronous ajax, otherwise you wouldn't get a warning about doing synchronous ajax

Comment: can't reproduce your problem. Works at my side!

Comment: Very Strange ! I've tried it in IE , there is no error in console but it still does not work . @charlietfl

Comment: What is the content of `2.html`. I guess it's a full html page with script tags in the head. You can't put a full html page inside a div. probably that is causing the error.

Comment: that error is only a warning and isn't a blocking error anyway

Comment: @kasperTaeymans : ` <strong> DONE! </strong> `

Comment: @charlietfl : yes the error is warning !

I found soloution and I'm posting it now ; I tested the same code in online free webhost and it just worked there !